# How to add ACE Editor highlighter rules in angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, ace-editor

I try to add custom highlighter rules. My example based on [this](https://medium.com/@ofir3322/create-an-online-ide-with-angular-6-nodejs-part-1-163a939a7929) and [this](https://medium.com/@jackub/writing-custom-ace-editor-mode-5a7aa83dbe50).

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import * as ace from 'ace-builds';

import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('codeEditor') codeEditorElmRef: ElementRef;
  private codeEditor: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var oop = ace.require('ace/lib/oop');
    var textHighlightRules = ace.require('ace/mode/text_highlight_rules').TextHighlightRules;

    const $rules = {
      start: [
        {
          regex: /sometext/,
          token: "keyword"
        },
        {
          regex: /othertext/,
          token: "keyword"
        }
      ]
    };

    const customHighlightRules = function CustomHighlightRules() {
      this.$rules = $rules;
    };

    oop.inherits(customHighlightRules, textHighlightRules);

    //exports.MyNewHighlightRules = customHighlightRules; //??
    const element = this.codeEditorElmRef.nativeElement;

    const options = {
      minLines: 14,
      maxLines: Infinity,
      highlightSelectedWord: true,
      enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
      enableSnippets: true,
      enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    };

    this.codeEditor = ace.edit(element, options);
    this.codeEditor.setTheme('ace/theme/github');
    this.codeEditor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/text');
    this.codeEditor.setShowFoldWidgets(true);
  }
}
```

I need "sometext" to be highlighted. How to adapt this example for an angular and typescript? I could not find any working examples where integration with angular is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create both Mode and HighlightRules like this:

```js
var oop = ace.require("ace/lib/oop");
var TextMode = ace.require("ace/mode/text").Mode;
var TextHighlightRules = ace.require("ace/mode/text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

var CustomHighlightRules = function(){
    this.$rules = {
        'start': [
            {
              regex: /\b(sometext|othertext)\b/,
              token: "keyword"
            }
        ]
    };
};

oop.inherits(CustomHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

var Mode = function() {
    this.HighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;
};
oop.inherits(Mode,TextMode);

(function() {
    this.$id = "ace/mode/custom";
}).call(Mode.prototype);


element = document.body
this.codeEditor = ace.edit(element, {
    value: "sometext not othertext",
    minLines: 14,
    maxLines: Infinity,
    highlightSelectedWord: true,
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    theme: 'ace/theme/github',
    showFoldWidgets: true,
    mode: new Mode
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 const oop = ace.acequire('ace/lib/oop');
    const TextMode = ace.acequire("ace/mode/text").Mode;
    const TextHighlightRules = ace.acequire("ace/mode/text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

    const customHighlightRules = function CustomHighlightRules() {
      this.$rules = {
        'start': [
          {
            regex: /\b(sometext|othertext)\b/,
            token: "keyword"
          }
        ]
      };
    };
    oop.inherits(customHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

    const Mode = function() {
      this.HighlightRules = customHighlightRules;
    };
    oop.inherits(Mode,TextMode);

    (function() {
      this.$id = "ace/mode/custom";
    }).call(Mode.prototype);

    this.editor.getEditor().getSession().setMode(new Mode)
```

blast from the future :) after some struggling started to work, thx

Comment: Hi @Csaba , Can you please provide the code in a Angular component? I'm struggling a bit